# create an image for a table filtered with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have jquery dropdown to filter a table.It works fine but I want to change the src of an image based on selected dropdown value
https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=6116967228740807515#editor/target=page;pageID=7527370011524018952;onPublishedMenu=pages;onClosedMenu=pages;postNum=0;src=link

Comment: Firstly no one can see that page as we don't have access rights. Secondly, please place all relevant code in the question here. As you've now seen, external links are not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help since the link is private right now, but it sounds like you need to write a .change listener on the form. This is triggered whenever the form is clicked:

Using JQuery:

```
$("#foo").change(function () {
        $('#img').attr('src','img-name.jpg');
});
```

You may also want to use the below line, in that function, so that you can dynamically assign an image based upon the option clicked.

```
$("#your_select").val();
```